# async_val is not a valid attribute for a IncludeRole

Tags: ansible

When executing

```
ansible -vvv localhost -m include_role -a "name=someName" --extra-vars="version=someVersion"
```

the output is

```
ansible 2.8.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Apr  9 2019, 14:30:50) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
script declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
ERROR! 'async_val' is not a valid attribute for a IncludeRole

The error appears to be in 'None': line 0, column 0, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

(could not open file to display line)
```

**Where is the async_val set?** I could not find it in any of the roles or config files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message comes from ansible's internals. This happens only when you use include_role as an ad-hoc command. It was [apparently fixed very recently](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/56163) and should be released for version 2.9.

Comment: Thank you very much! I could not find this PR.

Comment: I'm using Ansible 2.12 and still not working...